# How does GIN index deal with tsquery with both & and |?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

When I read the document, I just see an "extractValue" function, but I don't know how it works.

When I pass a query like

```
Select * 
from people 
WHERE people.belongings && to_tsquery('hat & (case | bag)')
```

(and I have a gin index on `people.belongings`)

would this query use the index? what would the extractValue do to this query?

=======

and another question, why not, or why can't, the GisT index to index an array's objects individually like GIN index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extractValue` is a support function that is used when building the index, not when searching it. In the case of full text search, it would be fed the `tsvector` and returns the index keys contained in it.

The support function used to get the keys in a `tsquery` would be `extractQuery`. For full text search, that would be `gin_extract_tsquery`. It is defined in `src/backend/utils/adt/tsginidx.c` if you are interested in the implementation. What is does is convert the `tsquery` into an internal representation that can be searched in the index.

The actual check if an index entry matches the search expression is done by `gin_tsquery_consistent`.

The support functions are described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xindex.html#XINDEX-GIN-SUPPORT-TABLE).